# How to use react router in v6 class components with id as parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-class-based-component

I have a Component Tutorials where I have to display description on the basis of ID and there I am embedding other component TutorialsSidebar which will display list of Tutorials. In TutorialsSidebar I have a link so when I click on that I want to pass Id as well and redirect to Tutorials component and use Id and on the basis of Id sent a api request and display description in the empty div. I want to achieve this in Class based component. Can I achieve this. Someone send me the syntax

```
render() {
return (
  <>
  <Navbar></Navbar>
  <BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Courses />} />
    <Route path="tutorials/:id" element={<Tutorial />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
    
    
    <Footer/>
  </>
);
```

In TutorialsSidebar used

```
<Link to={`/tutorials/${ID}`}>{title}</Link>
```

Instead of description I need to display description on the basis of Id from api request so how to get and use the id in Tutorials component

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQmkk.png)

Answer (score 0):

You  can set the coming id inside the router itself and it will be passed to the Component as prop, here is an example:

Use match.params for that in combination with Route's render prop:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/products/:id" render={({ match }) => (
       <AuthChecker>
          <Products id={match.params.id} />
       </AuthChecker>
    )} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: How would I  use this id in Tutorials Component. I think u gave syntax for App.js and this syntax is not supported in react router dom v6

Comment: please provide the code snippets too, so that i can clearly see what you are doing

Comment: Got the solution in Tutorials component `export default (props) => (
  <Tutorial
      {...props}
      params={useParams()}
  />
);` . IN componentDidMount method `const { id } = this.props.params;`